# Вопрос по ошибке make'а

Tags: linux, gnumake

Написал(взял из интернета) простейший Makefile для модуля ядра. Выдает ошибка, которую не могу понять.

Makefile

```
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
TARGET = mod_test
obj-m   := $(TARGET).o
all default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules 
clean:
    @rm -f *.o*.cmd.*.flags*.mod.c*.order
disclean: clean
```

Модуль

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Robert W. Oliver II");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple example Linux module.");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");
static int __init lkm_example_init(void) {
 printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, World!\n");
 return 0;
}
static void __exit lkm_example_exit(void) {
 printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, World!\n");
}
module_init(lkm_example_init);
module_exit(lkm_example_exit);
```

Ошибка

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/test/mod_test.o', needed by '__build'.  Stop.
Makefile:1655: recipe for target '_module_/usr/src/test' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/src/test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic'
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Исходя из того, что Вы привели, оказывается, что это не простейший makefile. Скорее всего проблемы в исходниках. Опять же, я не вижу target правила

Comment: `obj-m += ...`.

Comment: А вы поставили пакет с необходимыми файлами? Типа `linux-kbuild...`

Comment: 0andriy, были установлены следующие пакеты: ibssl-dev openssl build-essential zlib1g-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlibc unzip. Мог что-то забыть. Расскажите подробнее , чего не хватает, пожалуйста.